# Azure Data Factory Dynamic content default values per environment

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-data-factory

I hope somebody can help me understand how I can solve this issue.

In azure I have 3 separate environment:

- Development
- Staging
- Production

Each of this environment I have a Datafactory. Due to the large datasets I have I decided to build a CI CD pipeline to copy all the content of dev environment to staging and production every time I publish to `adf_publish`. This process work like a charm and I have all the datasets and linked services.

Here is where I start finding issues and I couldn't pass over them.

all 3 environments have cosmos databases with the exact same structure, but of course the url and access keys to cosmos are different.

Reading in Microsoft documentation, I have found that I can use `dynamic content` which is absolutely perfect.
I created the parameters:

[image]

when I try the connection in dev environment, the parameters blade opens and I can set the default values I want and the connection succeded.

I did the same configuration in staging and after the release pipeline, I could see the Parameters,

[image]

But as you can see from the screenshot nothing else has been configured. My first thought was that maybe I need to configure the default values and apply the changes but even after that, after each release the values get reseted.
Can anyone please help me understand how I can set the default values for each environment?

Please if there is any question or something I didn't explained well, just ask me and I will rephrase.

Thank you very much for any help you can provide me with.

UPDATE:
Finally I managed to sort the first part of my problem, which is make the release pipeline set the dynamic content in the cosmos connection[image]

But unfortunately my parameters value or they are hard coded or empty.

following this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment

I tried to create a `arm-template-parameters-definition.json` in the `adf_publish` in the root folder with this values:

```
{
"Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices":{
    "properties": {
        "parameters": {
            "DBNameAggregated": {
                "type": "string",
                "defaultValue": "test"
            },
            "DBAccessKey": {
                "type": "string",
                "defaultValue": "test"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

when I saved and pushed the changes, I refreshed the portal and published.
in my release pipeline I set the override param

```
-DBNameAggregated "test2"
```

but the release pipeline fails with the following error

```
Deployment template validation failed: 'The template parameters 'DBNameAggregated' in the parameters file are not valid; they are not present in the original template and can therefore not be provided at deployment time
```

I checked both my arm templates:

- TemplateForFactory: Here I have the parameters declared.
- TemplateParameters: Here the params are not declared

I am really hitting a wall here not knowing what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 3):

You will need to create the `arm-template-parameters-definition.json` under the main root folder.

[image: arm-template-parameters-definition]

If you want to parameterize the values, you need to add the below code.

In this example, I am parameterizing all values under `typeProperties` for cosmosdb linked service

```
"Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedServices": {
    "CosmosDB": {
        "properties": {
            "typeProperties": {
               "*": "="
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have updated this code, You will see the changes on the `ARMTemplateforFactory.json` file under the `adf_publish` branch.

Here are the values from the `armtemplateforfactory.json` file.

`CosmosDb1_connectionString`, `cosmosdbURL`, `CosmosDBKey` are parameterized.

```
"name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/CosmosDb1')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedServices",
        "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
        "properties": {
            "parameters": {
                "cosmosdbURL": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "defaultValue": "xyz"
                },
                "CosmosDBKey": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "defaultValue": "xyz"
                }
            },
            "annotations": [],
            "type": "CosmosDb",
            "typeProperties": {
                "connectionString": {
                    "type": "SecureString",
                    "value": "[parameters('CosmosDb1_connectionString')]"
                }
            }
        }
```

My actual code on the cosmosdb linked connection. Here I have assigned `xyz` to the `cosmosdburl` and `cosmosdbkey`

```
{
"name": "CosmosDb1",
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
"properties": {
    "parameters": {
        "cosmosdbURL": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "xyz"
        },
        "CosmosDBKey": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "xyz"
        }
    },
    "annotations": [],
    "type": "CosmosDb",
    "typeProperties": {
        "connectionString": "AccountEndpoint=@{linkedService().cosmosdbURL};Database=bhargavademo;AccountKey=@{linkedService().CosmosDBKey}"
    }
    }
}
```

The last step is, you need to update the `cosmosDBURL`, `CosmosDBKey`, connection string values on your `overridetemplateparameters` on the release pipeline.

[image: Override Template parameters]

Answer (score 0):

Connection Strings are secure strings and will not have a default value ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-resource-manager-custom-parameters#linkedservices:%7E:text=The%20connectionString%20property%20will%20be%20parameterized%20as%20a%20securestring%20value.%20It%20won%27t%20have%20a%20default%20value.%20It%20will%20have%20a%20shortened%20parameter%20name%20that%27s%20suffixed%20with%20connectionString.))

In order to retain the value you need to override the template parameters inside of the ARM deployment step during your CI/CD pipeline. The parameter is called {your linked service name}_connectionstring. You can find all the parameters inside of the *ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json* file.
[image]

For the default values of the linked service parameters (DBNameAggregated & DBAccessKey) follow the steps described in BhargavaGunnam-MSFT answer